# Let $X$ be $2m\times 2m$ skew-symmetric matrix of indeterminate, then $\det(X)$ is a perfect squre of polynomial ring $\Bbb{Z}[x^i_j]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry

I was reading Loring W.Tu's differential geometry book , there is a theorem in page 231, which says:

Let $X$ be $2m\times 2m$ skew-symmetric matrix of indeterminate, then $\det(X)$ is a perfect square of a polynomial ring $\Bbb{Z}[x^i_j]$

There is some terminology in algebra that I don't know, he prove it as follows:

Proof. Let $\mathbb{Q}\left(x_{j}^{i}\right)$ be the field generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by the indeterminates $x_{j}^{i}$. We know that $\operatorname{det} X \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}\left[x_{j}^{i}\right]$, because there exist values of $x_{j}^{i}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ for which $\operatorname{det} X \neq 0$. Thus, $X=\left[x_{j}^{i}\right]$ is a $2 m \times 2 m$ nonsingular skew-symmetric matrix over the field $\mathbb{Q}\left(x_{j}^{i}\right)$. By the discussion above, there is a matrix $A \in \operatorname{GL}\left(2 m, \mathbb{Q}\left(x_{j}^{i}\right)\right)$ such that
$$
\operatorname{det} X=\left(\frac{1}{\operatorname{det} A}\right)^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}\left(x_{j}^{i}\right)
$$
This proves that $\operatorname{det} X$ is a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}\left(x_{j}^{i}\right)$.

---

**I don't know what does "$\mathbb{Q}\left(x_{j}^{i}\right)$ be the field generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by the indeterminates $x_{j}^{i}$." means , and why "$X=\left[x_{j}^{i}\right]$ is a $2 m \times 2 m$ nonsingular skew-symmetric matrix over the field $\mathbb{Q}\left(x_{j}^{i}\right)$."**

Can someone explain a little bit?

Comment: I found a related link https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2654594/360262

Comment: $\Bbb Q(x_j^i)={\rm Frac}(\Bbb Q[x_j^i])$ is the fraction field of the polynomial ring in the variables $x_j^i$.